Creating an objective function for light intensity from light bulb in a 1x1m area - multi objective optimization
I am in high school and i just learnt basic opitmization with calculus.
Im doing a research task where I'm trying to find the best position for two light bulbs on a ceiling.
I decided on this question because there was a question in our textbook
picture of the answer to the question - dark spot between two light bulbs
The requirement is that it has to be on level with what we know or a bit harder. Optimisation is too easy so i looked into multi objective optimisation, but I'm not sure where and how to learn it?
Lets say there are 2 light bulbs with 40 candela that can be placed anywhere on a 1 x 1 m area (a ceiling)
I want to use multi objective optimization so that with the position of the light bulbs:

Minimise areas with light intensity below a certain threshold

Maximising overlap between light?


I kinda barely understand maulti obejctive optimization and I was wondering how would you even begin writing functions that represent these, or if multi objective optimization is even right for what I am trying to do?
theres nothing much online abt it
i just need some guidance for the assumptions I need to make and help for the functions :(( (idk how to write them)
OR is  my question too obvious? would it just be better to place the lights in the middle??
(btw the ceiling isnt actually 1x1, its a weird number but thats for simplifictaion)
Edit 2: sorry if this is too vague, I'm just looking for guidance on what to do

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your question is too vague for this site. How did you decide on this problem? I suspect it is too hard for someone who has just learned calculus. If you want to persist, you will have to [edit] the question to provide a lot more actual context - the functions you have written down and the outputs you want to maximize. (Do not try to clarify with comments. [edit] The question.)
